# How to check the malloc address is QWord aligned?

Tags: c, nvme

I want to test create NVMe I/O Submission Queue Invalid Queue Address Offset

I use C posix_memalign to alloc a memory range

But how to check that the address i get is QWord aligned?

I know if i want the address is word aligned then address end is 00h
and double word aligned address end is 000h

So is qword aligned address end is 0000h?

Can i check by below?

```
if( address & 0xF != 0 )
    printf("Not qword aligned");
```

Thanks

Comment: By the way, `h` at the end usually means hex, or four bits per digit.  The C way to specify a binary constant is `0b00`.  Also one trailing binary zero means the word is aligned on a two-byte boundary, two trailing binary zeroes that it's aligned on a four-byte boundary, and four that it's aligned on a 16-byte boundary, which I think is what you probably mean?

Comment: A bitwise operation on a pointer is not necessarily valid, bit converting `(uintptr_t)(void*)` will at least compile correctly.to an unsigned integral expression that can be used as the operand of `&`.

Comment: an address terminating in `0000h` is 64Kb aligned.... I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to test the low bits with a bitwise and.  There isn't a perfectly-portable way of doing that with no implementation-defined behavior, but that doesn't matter because you're targeting one specific architecture.  So, you can test that `p` is aligned on a 16-byte boundary, on any C compiler for the x86, with `(uintptr_t)(void*)p & 0x0f == 0`.

However, this is an XY problem: `posix_memalign()` is defined to do what you want. Indeed, `malloc()` is guaranteed to return memory that meets the strictest alignment requirements of any type, and you can check `alignof(max_align_t)`.

In this case, you might want to use `aligned_alloc()`, which exists in the standard library to allocate memory with a stricter alignment requirement, and has a simpler interface, or `calloc()`, which allows you to specify the element size and also zeroes out the memory.